# Python error handling in class hierarchy

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, error-handling

I am currently working on a subsystem in Python, which has a following structure:

1. Facade, which provides interface for communication with other subsystems (name it `MyFacade`)
2. Engine (singleton) - receives requests from facade and dispathes them to "working" classes (`MyEngine`)
3. Working modules - such as `MyFileSystem`, `MyNetwork`, `MyDB` and so on.

Thus there are three general levels: `Facade` - `Engine` - `Worker`. If an error occurs somewhere, `Facade` must get it and show it to client, and the application must not crash.

What is the best-practice way to organize error handling errors on all three levels of abstraction in Python?  If an error occurs on the lowest level (`Worker`) should I catch it, or return `None`/`False`?  What should be done on upper levels to provide necessary functionality and avoid violating DRY, SRP, and so on?

Suppose I have a function/method `worker_method` on `Worker` level. Inside this method I perform a number of operations. 
Most of them are critical - if they fail, I want to stop executing `worker_method` and report failure to `Engine`. 
However, I have one call inside `worker_method` that I don't care of, it's allowed to fail. So should it look something like this:

```
def worker_method(self):
    """..."""
    critical_call()
    another_critical_call()
    try:
         dummy_call()
    except Exception, e:
         # caught non-critical exception  
         logger.log_error(e.message)
    """..."""
```

Consider a method in `Engine` that calls the above one:

```
def engine_method(self):
    try:  
         some_engine_internal_stuff()
         """..."""
         data_from_worker = worker_instance.worker_method()
         """..."""
         self.set_last_error(None)
         return engine_operating(data_from_worker)
    except Exception, e:
         self.set_last_error(e.message)
         return None
```

Consider a method in `Facade` that calls the above one:

```
def facade_method(self):
    try:
        """..."""
        data_from_engine = engine_instance.engine_method()
        if data_from_engine is None and engine_instance.get_last_error() is not None:
            return facade_prepare_data_to_return_to_client(engine_instance.get_last_error())

        return facade_prepare_data_to_return_to_client(data_from_engine)
    except Exception, e:
        return facade_prepare_data_to_return_to_client(e.message)
```

In this case `Engine` instance works in "bulletproof" mode and prevents exceptions from approaching `Facade` level. Failures are indicated by return values.
On `Facade` level we again use try/catch because despite the fact that `Engine` is "bulletproof" there still can be exceptions in `Facade` methods and we must catch them in order to prevent app from possible crash.

Does this model satisfy Python best-practice and general design standards?
Can it be improved or simplified?

Comment: This is difficult to answer in the generic case - [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) is a common Python idiom, so there are some places you'll want to handle the errors right away, some cases where you want to handle them somewhere in the middle and some cases where you want them to bubble right up to the `Facade`.

Comment: I've got `log` functionality in `Engine`, so if an error occurs on either `Engine` or `Worker` level, I want to get it on `Engine`, log it and then send to `Facade` to show to the user if necessary.
Actually I always need to bubble up to `Engine` for logging and to `Facade` for informing the client.
I am familiar with EAFP but a bit confused about how to make use of it in this particular case.

Comment: I suspect that this quesion may be too broad for SO... but anyway... If Facade _must_ show _all_ errors to the client it makes sense to let all Exceptions bubble up to Facade. FWIW, intermediate levels can easily augment the error message (or even raise a totally new Exception) on any Exceptions that pass through them. A problem with this approach is that raising an Exception breaks the flow of processing, so it can be more convenient to handle the problem at a lower level, logging it if necessary.

Comment: My point is that some errors in `Engine` might be part of the normal program flow (a `StopIteration` exception ending a for loop, for example), so you won't want those to be logged/reported. Your program will have loads of different *"this particular"* cases, so the question as it stands is unanswerable.

Comment: IMAO, try - except clauses within the engine should catch minor exceptions, and log them. More important exceptions should be caught by Facade. Another way to do it may be to catch everything within engine, and re-raise important exceptions with additional information to be passed on to Facade.

Comment: @Aaron, I agree in with you in general. What we have so far is:
1)`Workerks` should simply ingnore exceptions
2)`Engine` should catch all exceptions and decide what to do; if necessary - bubble the exception up to `Facade` level using `raise`
Did I get you right?

Comment: In your example what's the point in `try: ... except: raise`? Just let the error bubble up naturally!

Comment: @jonrsharpe the point of `try: ... except: raise` is to decorate exceptions with additional information. @Emons that's mostly what I was getting at, but for the engine to catch exceptions, don't catch them in the workers. If a worker fails due to an exception that is tolerable, have the engine re-start the worker.

Comment: @Aaron but in the OP's example *they weren't doing that!* Note that you can only `@` one user per comment, but the OP will be notified anyway (as this is their question).

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're correct that they weren't, but that is a useful purpose for adding that clause. Also I had no idea about only one `@` thx :)